# why do Python functions have name?

Tags: python

I don't see any significance/use of func_name. Two different function can have same name,It's enough to know reference to function. Refer below sample code

```
def a():
    print "function a"
b=a
def a():
    print "new function a"
>>> b.func_name
'a'
>>> a.func_name
'a'
```

a() and b() both have same function name, But both are reference to different function object.

```
>>> b.func_name
'a'
>>> a.func_name
'a'
```

Can some one help me to understand why python store func_name which has no use?

Comment: @deceze, actually the name in the stacktrace comes from `a.func_code.co_name`

Comment: For documentation? At least, the function name is reported by `help(a)`.

Comment: And as a notice , it's `__name__` in Python 3.x

Comment: We get to know function name from help, but it will confuse me only, I might be having two func_name with different description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is used for some things. `repr(fn)` uses `fn.func_name` to display the name of the function. `help(fn)` also uses `fn.func_name` for the documentation.

Pickling a function also uses the `func_name` attribute, both as the name stored in the pickle, and to check that the function is defined in the module (so you can't pickle a function defined inside another function as it checks there is a function with the same name and the same code object defined in the module).

Note that stack traces use the name attached to the code object `fn.func_code.co_name` so you can't change the name that appears in a stack trace as that is a read-only attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Functions have names to be named. As an example of use :

```
import math
for name in dir(math):
    try :
        if eval('math.'+name)(0)==0 : print (name,end=', ')  
    except : pass
print('\b\b know origin of things.')
```

prints : *"asin, asinh, atan, atanh, ceil, degrees, erf, expm1, fabs, floor, isinf, isnan, log1p, radians, sin, sinh, sqrt, tan, tanh, trunc know origin of things."*

`__name__` can bee seen as first name for human, you have normally no reason to change it. Python unlike C allow redeclaration. It's your responsability to make good use.